# Dependence of a pendulum's period on temperature

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, temperature, harmonic-oscillator

Does the time period of pendulum just increases with temperature or proportionately with temperature. If former is correct why latter is incorrect

Comment: As the length of string increases

Comment: I've edited your title. Please use titles that describe the question.

Answer (score 0):

The period $T$ for a pendulum is given by the following equation.

$$T\approx 2\pi \sqrt{\frac Lg}$$

As you can see in this equation, the period depends only on the length $L$ of the pendulum and the acceleration $g$ of gravity. The pendulum's period increases proportionally to the square root of its length and the square root of gravitational acceleration. The effects of temperature on a pendulum are insignificant. Therefore the period of a pendulum does not increase proportionally with temperature.

Comment: As a practical matter pendulum clocks need some kind of temperature compensation mechanism exactly because of the relation you cite. After all, the length of a naive pendulum depends on the temperature. There are two common schemes for building temperature compensated pendulums.

Comment: The OP's issue here may be one of understanding why a multiple choice question was marked as it was. If so the answer would be that the period is varies in proportion to the square root of temperature and not proportionally to the temperature.